# How to interpret this problem of multicriteria decision

Tags: optimization, multi-objective-optimization, multicriteria-decision-analysis

I am trying to optimise a cost function that consists of three parameters (A,B,C) using weighted sum approach for the selection of optimal technique out of three techniques.  Parameter A unit is in percentage while parameter B and C unit is milliseconds. Parameter A is beneficial attribute, while B and C are non-beneficial attributes.

```
min(cost)=Aw1+Bw2+Cw3
```

The following data, normalised by considering beneficial and non-beneficial attributes. I am trying to minimise the cost of the function of t weighted sum approach that provides the best technique out of three technique with supplied user weights. However, I noticed that for better input the cost function is higher for instance for 4.466916 the normalised value is 1 and for 24.2542 it's 1 in below data

```
Parameter B                 Min
4.466916 27.07074 24.57503 4.466916 
24.2542  27.07074 25.95272 24.2542
```

Normalised data after applying formula xmin/x

```
1 0.165009  0.181766
1 0.895956  0.934553
```

Below is the data of Parameter A data which consists of data of three techniques T1,T2,T3

```
  T1    T2      T3       Max
0.6233  0.8253  0.8324  0.8324      
0.8063  0.8253  0.8311  0.8311
```

Normalised data after applying formula x=x/xmax

```
0.748799 0.991444 1
0.97016  0.993021 1
```

However, for above data I am trying to understand and couldn't understand that for better input the cost function is higher which should be minimum for instance for 4.466916 the normalised value is 1 and for 24.2542 which is not a better input its one. Would anyone please me in understand this

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! I suggest you re-read your question and edit it to make it clearer. I, personally, read it twice and still couldn't understand your question (e.g., "Below is the data of Parameter A data which consists of data of three techniques T1,T2,T3" has data repeated 3 times. What is this data? Are they different data? Can you use an alternative to data for whatever that's not referring to the same thing?)